# test is data available in `io.ReadWriteCloser`

Tags: go, io

`io.ReadWriteCloser` has blocking `Read()` until data available to read.

What if I want to test if it has data available to read, without actually `Read()` it. Since I need to do some other processing between:

- It has data available to read

and

- io.Copy(thisReadWriteCloser, anotherReadWriteCloser)

Comment: It is impossible to determine whether a call to Read will block or return quickly with data.

Comment: Does reading the data have a side effect that you need to avoid/postpone?

Comment: Yes, I updated my ticket, the next action I would like to do is `io.Copy(thisReadWriteCloser, anotherReadWriteCloser)`, so by doing `Read()`, I already advance the reader, the data is not in the original shape anymore when passing into `io.Copy()`

Answer (score 0):

using `bufio.Reader` `Peek()` function

```
bi := bufio.NewReader(i)
bi.Peek(1)
```

But I have follow up issue not able to re-use the original `io.ReadWriteCloser` after executing the `bi.Peek(1)`:  [convert from `bufio.Reader` to `io.ReadWriteCloser`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75466833/convert-from-bufio-reader-to-io-readwritecloser)

Comment: If the buffer is empty when you call `Peek`, it will call the underlying `Read` (which is blocking, as you said).

Comment: @HymnsForDisco sure I want the blocking behavior, but not the reading behavior once unblocked, this `Peek()` does the job for me.